# Не видит сторонние библиотеки в WEB приложении

Tags: java, веб-программирование, исключения, servlet, зависимости

Запускаю простое WEB приложение на java с использованием tomcat и сервлетов сборка с maven, и при использовании класса, который использует сторонние библиотеки org.apache.poi выбрасывает ошибку NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook. при замене и использовании других классов выбрасывает ошибку на них. В тестах все работает и находит все зависимости. А через сервлеты на сайте ничего.
Как правильно прописывать зависимости в файле poi или куда их нужно выкладывать чтобы веб приложение их видело или они подгружались через maven в веб проект.
Собственно файлы:
pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yurets_y</groupId>
    <artifactId>utl2-plan-chart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

list.jsp - в котором возникают проблемы

```html
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>

<body>
<div>
    <div>
       
    <form method="post">
        <input list="stationList" name="stationList">
        <datalist id="stationList">
            <option value="Station one">
            <%
                List<String> names = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("stationList");
                for (String s : names) {
                    out.println("<option value=" + s + ">");
                }
            %>
        </datalist>
     </form>

</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Сам сервлет, который обращается к файлу базы данных:

```
package app.servlets;

import app.model.ChartModel;
import app.model.Model;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class AddUserServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
{
      protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, 
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws 
      javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, 
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws 
    javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    ChartModel model = ChartModel.getInstance();
    List<String> names = model.getStationNames();
    request.setAttribute("userNames",names);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("views/add.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

И собственно сам java клас, который использует сторонние библиотеки:

```
package app.model;

import app.model.bin.Station;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ChartModel {
    private static ChartModel ourInstance = new ChartModel();
    private Set<Station> stationSet;

public static ChartModel getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private ChartModel() {
    stationSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    URL url = ChartModel.class.getResource("/datares/stationsUZ.xlsx");
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            stationSet = loadStationsFromExcel(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println("Не удалось загрузить данные из списка!");
    }
}

private Set<Station> loadStationsFromExcel(File file) throws IOException, Exception {
    Set<Station> stations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    XSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet myExcelSheet = myExcelBook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowIndex = 1;
    XSSFRow row;
    Station station;
    do {
        row = myExcelSheet.getRow(rowIndex++);
        if (row == null) {
            break;
        }
        station = getStationFromRow(row);
        if (station != null) {
            stations.add(station);
        }else break;

    } while (true);

    myExcelBook.close();

    return stations;
}

private Station getStationFromRow(XSSFRow row) {
    int code;
    String rusName;
    String ukrName;
    String administration;
    String railDepartment;
    int node;

    if (row.getCell(0) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int i = 0;
    code = (int)row.getCell(i++).getNumericCellValue();
    rusName = row.getCell(i++).getStringCellValue();
    ukrName = row.getCell(i++).getStringCellValue();
    administration = row.getCell(i++).getStringCellValue();
    railDepartment = row.getCell(i++).getStringCellValue();
    node = (int) row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue();
    return new Station(code, rusName, ukrName, administration, railDepartment,node);
}

public Set<Station> getStationSet() {
    return stationSet;
}
public List<String> getStationNames(){
    return stationSet
            .stream()
            .map(Station::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public List<String> getFakeList(){
    List<Station> model = new ArrayList<>();
    model.add(new Station(1,"Первая","Перша","УЗ","ЮЗЖД",1));
    model.add(new Station(2,"Вторая","Друга","УЗ","ЮЗЖД",1));
    model.add(new Station(3,"Третья","Третя","УЗ","ЮЗЖД",1));
    model.add(new Station(4,"Четвертая","Четверта","УЗ","ЮЗЖД",1));
    model.add(new Station(5,"Пятая","Пята","УЗ","ЮЗЖД",1));
    return model.stream()
            .map(Station::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Comment: покажите весь pom.xml

Comment: В pom.xml зависимости у вас объявлены как `provided`, что подразумевает их наличие у сервлет-контейнера Tomcat (например, в папках $CATALINA_HOME/lib или $CATALINA_BASE/lib). Точно сейчас не вспомню куда лучше положить джарник. Если вы собираете проект как war, то можно в pom.xml у зависимости убрать `<scope>provided</scope>` и копать в сторону добавления зависимости в war-ник.

Comment: На данном этапе только тестирую возможности, так сказать учебный проект. Есть ли возможность объявлять зависимости, чтобы их видел tomcat при запуске приложения через intellij idea, или на данном этапе лучше все зависимости копировать в tomcat X.X/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте в pom.xml после

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

вот это :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```